# How can i get my main image to cover my Masthead and button section below

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I would like the main image to be in the background of the masthead and the button section below, so it all looks like one smooth image with three different sections.

my website is www.monoalarms.co.uk/wp

Something similar to this websites Masthead design design: https://jacksonfire.co.uk/security/intruder/

Can i CSS code this or will it be a more complicated process?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with pure CSS:

```
.your-element {
  background: url('path/to/your/image') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover; // meaning it will cover the whole size
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just dont fully understand what i should be putting in the .your-element section? And also is the path to my image simply the folder structure i follow to get to where the image is saved on my computer?

Comment: Hi @Marcburke your images are traditionally on an `assets` or `public` folder inside of your projects. I guess you should practice CSS basics, here's (among a whole lot) an URL where you can find answers and practice: https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: Thank you i will look into that but i am constrained by time at the moment. could you please help me then to remove the small piece of whitespace that currently sits underneath the main banner and above the buttons?